# Send one file of Dropzone to multiple urls

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I've been using [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/://) for a while and it works perfectly. Although, I had to change my approach. I used to send the file to an url (as usual in Dropzone), however, I need to send it to multiple urls (the same file). I couldn't find an answer. Some one know the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a built in feature in dropzone to do that, but you can send an additional `xmlhttprequest` for each additional url, you can send this second request in any event that gets the dropzone file object.

Here a bare minimum example sending it when the default upload was successful:

js:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

    // This is the default dropzone url in case is not defined in the html
    url: 'upload.php',

    init: function() {

        this.on('success', function(file){

            // Just to see default serve response on console
            console.log(file.xhr.responseText);

            // Creat a new xmlhttprequest with the second url
            secondRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            secondRequest.open('POST', 'upload2.php', true);

            // Just to see second server response on success
            secondRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if(secondRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && secondRequest.status === 200) {
                    console.log(secondRequest.responseText);
                }
            };

            // Create a new formData and append the dropzone file
            var secondRequestContent = new FormData();
            secondRequestContent.append('file', file, file.name);

            // Send the second xmlhttprequest
            secondRequest.send(secondRequestContent);

        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks wallek876 for your response.
But I end up using the image base64 in 'addedfile' event and called a function from that.