# dropzonejs aspx how to get the full path of the file to upload

Tags: dropzone.js

I'm checking out Dropzonejs in an aspx page using vb.net.  I can get the name of the file that will be processed for upload but it doesn't give the full path.  My understanding (wrong as it may be) is that you need to do the upload in code behind but to do that I'd need to full path to the file.  Right now i have this for the javascript code

```
 Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        maxFilesize: 2 // MB
        , url: "/DropZoneJS/Test1.aspx?tid=<%=Request.QueryString("tid")%>"

    };
```

In code behind when i look at the request.querystring("tid") as mentioned before it give me the file name... say test.jpg.  What i need would be for example c:\trash\test.jpg.  What have i missed or what other options does dropzonejs give me to get the name of the file so that it can be processed.

thanks
shannon

Comment: I believe for security reasons that is not possible, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav " "). Or this [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748250/send-one-file-of-dropzone-to-multiple-urls/40817108#40817108 " ") for an alternative.